# Max aggregate function with autonumber and date field in access

Tags: database, ms-access

I have ran into a problem recently. One of the tables I have in MS Access database contains multiple fields but the main focus is on an autonumber field and date field. When I try to apply Select query with  Max(autonumber) function and where clause containing date field, the wrong value or rather empty column is shown. as soon as i remove the date field from the where clause, the value is returned fine. My query is attached. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT MAX(serial) AS Expr1
FROM coaDetails
WHERE (((coaDetails.[title])='CLAIMS')AND ((coaDetails.[dates])=#04/08/2018#));
```

The above query, serial is autonumber while dates is date/time with format as dd/mm/yyyy

There is no error in the query but it just gives wrong value. as soon as date condition is removed it gives results.

Comment: Questions like this can be impossible to figure out without a sample of your data, as well as your expected output.  For example, is there a **time** attached to this date in the table? What happens if you use `>` instead of `=` with the time? (Also, see how to create a **[mcve]**.)

Comment: Also you can tidy up your query like this: `SELECT MAX(serial) FROM coaDetails WHERE [title]='CLAIMS' AND [dates]=#04/08/2018#` ...(is hasn't changed anything, but the rest was superfluous.)    ...and also, the *column's date format* is irrelevant.  What is your system's date format; that's how dates need to be specified when inside `#these#`

Comment: @ashleedawg my current system date format is dd/mm/yyyy and when i specify that it gives false value. but when i place mm/dd/yyyy format between # it starts giving correct result. What could be the reason ?

Comment: What makes you say your system date format is `dd/mm/yyyy`? Perhaps double check by going to your Start menu and typing `date format` and click the option to see the ways dates/times are displayed, and check the format under `Short Date`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the mm/dd/yyyy or yyyy/mm/dd format for the string expression for the date value:

```
WHERE (((coaDetails.[title])='CLAIMS')AND ((coaDetails.[dates])=#2018/08/04#));
```

Comment: This seems to me too the issue: either something to do with the date format, or maybe some time value in the date.

Comment: It is not "seems to be", it **is** the issue. You must apply a valid format to string expressions for date values to concatenate these into SQL string. And that format is not dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score 2):

In the SQL code, the dates have to be formatted the american way: `#mm/dd/yyyy#`. In the query design grid, which is a user-friendly, graphical view of the SQL code in the back, the format depends on your regional settings.

Therefore, just use the month first:

```
SELECT MAX(serial) AS Expr1
FROM coaDetails
WHERE (((coaDetails.[title])='CLAIMS')AND ((coaDetails.[dates])=#08/04/2018#));
```

Comment: well here in Pakistan we use dd/mm/yyyy so how can i modify my query to pick the right result when date column is in dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: In the query design grid, enter the criteria in pakistanian format. When switching to SQL view, you will see it the other way around (and vice versa).